# Arguing against statistical power

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interaction, statistical-power

I'm arguing with a colleague. We have some pooled time-series data (i.e., longitudinal data involving many individuals) and we're trying to quantify an effect (e.g., we need to measure the mean and variance of the effect in the population). I have a suspicion that the data really consists of multiple subgroups (or more like, an interaction effect with another continuous variable) and that their means and variances are probably different. This hunch is based on an intuitive understanding of the data. For instance, imagine the response to a drug in the adult population is different to kids. In this case, age is analogous to the continuous interaction term I'm referring to.

I've done a crude Welch's t-test, splitting the dataset into two halves along the middle of this suspected interaction term and found that the two means are (just) statistically significantly different. However, my colleague insists that statistical power trumps specificity and that we should be pooling and use as much data as available. How do I argue against this?

Comment: Have you made some exploratory data analysis like plotting the density (with a krenel density estimator like the R function `density`) and checked whether the distribution is unimodal or multimodal? Or you can try a Gaussin mixture model and let the number of mixtures be estimated.

Comment: Signal to noise is pretty low (we're talking about 3-5% correlation). So it just looks like a mess on a scatter plot. Nonetheless there's enough observations to pick up the faint signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you interaction term is a [hidden confounder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding)? In this case, indeed you should compute your effects conditioned on that confounder. The average causal effect would then be computed with the standard formula for [backdoor adjustment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confounding).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Then how would you fight the statistical power argument? After all, the confounding variable is my interpretation and he's clearly seeing different things - in having a larger dataset and being more robust.

Comment: When there is a hidden confounder, not adjusting for it will in general always give you wrong results, no matter how much data you have. More data helps you with reducing the effect of noise, it doesn't change a wrong model into a right model.

Comment: That is a very good point. Thanks!

Comment: Unless the model is a deep neural network...? :P

Comment: @CharlieParker: In a way, a deep neural network is never really a wrong model.

Comment: @frank why do you say that? Universal approximation theorem?

Comment: @CharlieParker yes

Comment: @frank I'd probably debate that it's more nuanced. e.g. universal approx theorem doesn't capture things like finite data + there is also the variance + bias + optimization issues. I'd argue the specific architecture of the NN matters a lot since it addresses all those issues - probably the bias most. Thanks for discussion!

Comment: @CharlieParker Yes, there is plenty of nuances. Wanted to be really vague by saying "in a way" :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have two populations, it doesn't make sense to model one mean.

I think you should model the difference as a fixed effect (i.e. as a covariate). This means you estimate two means, but gain the power from having one model - best of both worlds?

Comment: I guess the difficulty is in proving to someone that there are two (or more) groups. I've artificially classified them into two groups but there could be more along the continuous interaction term. The signal-to-noise isn't very high that's why my colleague is so fixated on having more observation = higher statistical power.

Comment: You lose very little power for a continuous predictor that has no effect.